# Representations And Characters Of Groups Second Edition

Tags: representation-theory, representations-by-quadratic-forms, representation-of-algebras

1. Let $G=\left\langle x: x^{3}=1\right\rangle \cong C_{3}$, and let $V$ be the 2-dimensional $\mathbb{C G}$ module with basis $v_{1}, v_{2}$, where
   $$
   v_{1} x=v_{2}, v_{2} x=-v_{1}-v_{2}
   $$
   (This is a $\mathbb{C} G$-module, by Exercise 3.2.) Express $V$ as a direct sum of irreducible $\mathbb{C} G$-submodules.

Let G  kx: x3  1l  C3, and let V be the 2-dimensional CGmodule
with basis v1, v2, where
v1x  v2, v2x  ÿv1 ÿ v2:
(This is a CG-module, by Exercise 3.2.)
Express V as a direct sum of irreducible CG-submodules.

(شیکار:(بەوێنە لەگەڵ دانراوە
solution:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4cmC.jpg)

Comment: Hi there, your question as currently phrased is likely to attract close votes and downvotes. To avoid this and also to get the best answers suited to your understanding, I suggest checking [How to ask a good question.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/)

Comment: You are off to a rough start with posting at Math.SE, two tersely phrased Questions accompanied by self-answers given in the form of images.  Please slow down and explain clearly what problem you wanted help with here.

Comment: @amWhy:  That's the other posting by this OP, true, but it's about a different exercise (perhaps two exercises?) in the same chapter.  I'm inclined to vote to close both for lack of context, not as a duplicate.

Answer (score -1):

Solution: representation in Exersise 8.1

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1P04.jpg)